# Convert column with list of tuples to many columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, tuples

I have a dataframe where a column contains uneven lists of tuples. The tuples will all be of same length, only the lists are uneven. I want to melt this column in-frame so that new columns will be appended to the existing one and rows will be duplicated. Like so:

```
df
   name     id       list_of_tuples
0  john doe    abc-123  [('cat',100,'xyz-123'),('cat',96,'uvw-456')]
1  bob smith    def-456  [('dog',98,'rst-789'),('dog',97,'opq-123'),('dog',95,'lmn-123')]
2  bob parr    ghi-789  [('tree',100,'ijk-123')]

df_new
   name            id       val_1 val_2 val_3
0  john doe        abc-123  cat   100   xyz-123
1  john doe        abc-123  cat   96    uvw-456
2  bob smith       def-456  dog   98    rst-789
3  bob smith       def-456  dog   97    opq-123
4  violet parr     def-456  dog   95    lmn-123
5  violet parr     ghi-789  tree  100   ijk-123
```

For my current method I'm creating a new dataframe where I'm using the chain feature from itertools, but I want to get away from creating a whole other dataframe and merging it back on the 'id' column.

Here's my current code:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(df.matches)),columns=['val_1','val_2','val_3']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_new['id'] = np.repeat(df.id.values, df['list_of_tuples'].str.len())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unnest your list then we do `concat`

```
s=df.list_of_tuples
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(s.str.len())}).reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(s.values))],axis=1)
Out[118]: 
        id     0    1        2
0  abc-123   cat  100  xyz-123
1  abc-123   cat   96  uvw-456
2  def-456   dog   98  rst-789
3  def-456   dog   97  opq-123
4  def-456   dog   95  lmn-123
5  ghi-789  tree  100  ijk-123
```

Comment: @guru just add one more column here `pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(s.str.len()),'name':df.name.repeat(s.str.len())}).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Update using pandas `explode` in 0.25.3+

```
dfi = df.explode('list_of_tuples')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dfi['list_of_tuples'].to_list(), 
                   index=[dfi['name'], dfi['id']])\
        .add_prefix('val_')
df1.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        name       id val_0  val_1    val_2
0   john doe  abc=123   cat    100  xyz-123
1   john doe  abc=123   cat     96  uvw-456
2  bob smith  def-456   dog     98  rst-789
3  bob smith  def-456   dog     97  opq-123
4  bob smith  def-456   dog     95  lmn-123
5   bob parr  ghi-780  tree    100  ijk-123
```

---

Let use `apply` with `pd.Series`:

```
df.set_index('id').list_of_tuples  #Set id as index and select list_of_tuples column
  .apply(pd.Series)                #apply pd.series to separate elements of list 
  .stack()                         #stack the elements vertically
  .apply(pd.Series)                #apply pd.Series to separate elements of tuples
  .add_prefix('val_')              #add prefix of val_ to all columns
  .reset_index()                   #Reset index to move id back into frame as column
  .drop('level_1', axis=1)         #Drop not need level_1 column from stack
```

Output:

```
        id val_0  val_1    val_2
0  abc-123   cat    100  xyz-123
1  abc-123   cat     96  uvw-456
2  def-456   dog     98  rst-789
3  def-456   dog     97  opq-123
4  def-456   dog     95  lmn-123
5  ghi-789  tree    100  ijk-123
```

Edited to handle question edit of adding 'name' to dataframe:

```
df.set_index(['name','id']).list_of_tuples
  .apply(pd.Series)
  .stack()
  .apply(pd.Series)
  .add_prefix('val_')
  .reset_index(level=-1,drop=True)
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        name       id val_0  val_1    val_2
0   John Doe  abc-123   cat    100  xyz-123
1   John Doe  abc-123   cat     96  uvw-456
2  Bob Smith  def-456   dog     98  rst-789
3  Bob Smith  def-456   dog     97  opq-123
4  Bob Smith  def-456   dog     95  lmn-123
5   Bob Parr  ghi-789  tree    100  ijk-123
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I'll be going with the comment above as it was much faster compared to the apply(pd.Series) approach.

Comment: @guru Yes, yes.  That is a much much faster approach.  apply pd.Series is slow.  Wen has perfect solutions.